# Encyclopedia of Mathematical Proofs with no English

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, first-order-logic, proof-theory, reference-works

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a modern book that builds a subset of elementary number theory from Peano axioms preferably in a Principia Mathematica fashion?

Or similarly an encyclopedia of mathematical proofs in some branches of mathematics only using the language of first-order logic and ZFC but not the English language.

Wiki proofs is an encyclopedia of proofs for example, but you cannot feed it to a computer program for example.

Comment: https://github.com/Novatux/coq-proofs/ has quadratic reciprocity in Coq (and various other facts, like Wilson).

Comment: See also Mizar, Isabelle and HOL Light.  For example, http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6474

Comment: But you want it in a book, on paper?  How quaint!

Comment: http://www.lemma-one.com/ProofPower/examples/examples.html is another potentially relevant reference - but it does contain some English $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a web search, this one looks interesting and maybe meets your needs:

http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html